# React and useState(): multiple re-renders if initial state is a string

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

So I have a functional component that displays an iframe. The `src`-property for the iframe is set in `useState()`.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function ComponentWithIframe() {

    const [iframeUrl, setIframeUrl] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
      // some axios-requests
      ... setIframeUrl(responseFromAxios);
    });

    return (
        <div className='Iframe'>
            <iframe
                id="my_iframe"
                src={iframeUrl}
                width="100%" height='800px'
                title="I am an Iframe"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now here's the strange thing: If `useState()` is initialized with a string, the component does multiple re-renders on mount (3 times). For example:

```
const [iframeUrl, setIframeUrl] = useState("There is no url defined");
```

But when I initialize `useState()` with `undefined`, then the component is rendered only once and everything works fine.

I found this solution more by accident and don't understand why it is working like this. Research didn't bring any explanation. Neither the official React Docs nor in-depth explanation sites like [this](https://dev.to/busypeoples/notes-on-typescript-react-hooks-28j2) or [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/a-guide-to-usestate-in-react-ecb9952e406c/). Even here on StackOverflow, I couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know what causes this behavior?

Comment: We cannot really tell why, without seeing the full source of the component

Answer (score 1):

I think the re-render occurs because there is no dependency array.

It should more like this,

```
useEffect(() => {
      // some axios-requests
      ... setIframeUrl(responseFromAxios);
    }, [])    // <- This Array
```

Refer: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: Hi Shri, I tried this out, but unfortunately the problem is still there. I tried with empty array and with dependencies. Such a strange behavior!